# Clickable reference in Latex

Tags: bibliographies

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{flexisym}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\bibitem{YFA} Y.Z. Fan,
\newblock On spectral integral variations of mixed graphs,
\newblock {\em Linear Algebra and its Applications}, 374 (2003) 307-316.
\end{document}
```

I am trying to give the reference as a clickable reference so that when one clicks, one can get the research paper directly on internet. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`hyperref` package enables many clickable links in the document. It allows you to have internet hyperlinks in the document. It also forms an outline for the document taking into account its sectioning. Your MWE was not 'minimal' so I've reframed it as follows. You can use `\href{link}{text}` for your purpose.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
You can know more about hyperreferencing \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500496/174620}{here}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does that work in a \bibitem??